# Stopped Current Question

Tags: electric-current

If current is in a loop but has a branch of say a length of wire that is open ended, the current flows to the end of the length of wire and stops.  Do the negative electrons flow back into the circuit when the current is stopped or do they simply pile up on the end of the open ended wire?

Answer (score 0):

The current *doesn't* flow to the end of the length of the wire in any significant amount. Realistically, there may be a tiny capacitance between the end of the wire and somewhere else in the circuit, but aside from that, no current flows down that branch in the first place.

If there is a capacitance, whatever charge build up there would usually discharge when the current is stopped, just like in a capacitor.

Comment: Why wouldn't the current flow to the end of the wire?  The electrons would not know the current is stopped.  If a creek runs off of a river does the water not flow down the creek until it hits a dam?

Comment: But the question is what direction of flow would the negative electrons be in said creek (branch)?

Comment: Bruce, the wire is the (water) canal and the air around are the walls. So at the end of the wire is a wall and a “water”fall of electrons doesn’t occur.

Comment: Bruce, see what happens in an antenna rod.

Comment: @Bruce-TPU Exactly as HolgerFiedler says, there's nothing pushing the electrons into (or out of) the branch. The only thing there *might* be to allow current to flow in the branch is a potential difference caused by capacitive coupling of the end of the wire to another part of the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

In order for for current to flow (negatively charged electrons to travel from one point to another) there must a driving force/potential difference. In the case of a loop of wire connected to some source of emf, say a battery, electrons are drawn towards the other end of the wire by the potential difference in the two ends of the battery. The electrons then travel down the medium (the wire) as it provides the path of least resistance to get to the other side of that potential difference.

If there is now a branch in that loop of wire, negative charges tend not to travel down that branch as they are more drawn to the other side of the potential difference than they are to the branch. If you thing of the negative side of the battery as -1 and the positive side +1, than before there was battery the whole wire can be that of as being at 0, and then the end the branch can also be thought of as being at 0, so the electrons have a stronger emf driving them around the wire rather than into the branch.

Now, electrons do not actually flow all the way around the wire. There is already a chain of electrons within the wire, and when one electron travels from the battery into the wire, it pushes an electron at the end of the chain into the other side of the battery. In this way, charge is able to travel a very far distance without individual electrons having to travel very far at all. (Think, flipping a light switch causes your light to turn on immediately)

Thus, when thinking of the driving force pushing electrons down the wire (which has a branch)very few electrons travel into the branch, and thus very little charge accumulates at the end of the branch. That very little amount of charge, relative to the amount of charge traveling around the loop, can be thought of as essentially no charge, and there is no charge to dissipate when the battery is disconnected.

That essentially zero charge is not exactly 0, and to answer your question, they do simply pile up on the end of the open ended wire. This amount of charge is so small that it is negligable.